# AWS CLI DynamoDB with shell variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-dynamodb, sh

I am trying to put a variable in the AWS CLI DynamoDB command for add a row in a table:

```
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name table_name --item '{"id_proceso": {"N": "1"}, "fecha_proceso": {"S": "20210707170486"}, "status": {"S": "OK"}, "fecha_termino": {"S": "fecha_termino_var"  } }' --region us-east-1
```

Where `fecha_termino_var` it should be a variable. example: `fecha_termino_var=(date +'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')`

but I have tried various ways but I have not managed to do it, is there any way to enter a variable in a aws cli command line?

The goal it is to add a row, which will contain a variable of the date in real time.

I've tried various ways but it just adds the variable type, in this case "`date`", or just the variable name in text plain "`fecha_termino_var`".

I'm working in a shell (.sh) to do this.

Failed image adds:

[image]
[image]

Comment: " without success" its not specific. Exactly what is happening? Why do you have space in `$ {date}`? Why do you use single quotes?

Comment: what `date=(date +'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')` is supposed to do? Can you explain? You are overwriting date with date?

Comment: without success I mean that sometimes it inserts the row but only the text or it gives syntax error

Comment: "date" is just an example to save the date inside that column, it doesn't necessarily have to have the same variable name. the goal is to save a variable within the command line

Comment: This is `date=(date +'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')` wrong. Is this bash? What do you think it does?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/19n0j8n there I just put the variable intro ", and it appear error parsing parameter

Comment: I have tried with backslashes like: "\${variable}\" but happened the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows that you are **missng** `"` infront of `fecha_termino.` So it should be:

```
, "fecha_termino":
```

not:

```
, fecha_termino":
```

Update:

The full correct command is:

```
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name mcp_control_proceso --item '{"id_proceso": {"N": "1"}, "fecha_proceso": {"S": "20210707170487"}, "status": {"S": "OK"}, "fecha_termino": {"S": "'"${fecha_termino_var}"'"} }' --region us-east-1
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, after this fix it adds the row, but in another way like "$fecha_termino" https://prnt.sc/19n297b

Comment: @Sebastián This is due to single quotes. Check my first comment "Why do you use single quotes? " Don't use single quotes to wrap your string. It does not resolve veriables.

Comment: How it should be? The code I added last one it's:  "fecha_termino": {"S": "$fecha_termino"  }

Comment: @Sebastián Sorry, I don't know. Your real code is different than in the question. Its difficult to speculate what actually you are actually using.

Comment: sorry, already fixed, I just want to insert a variable inside variable, "data": {"S": "$variable"} but it seems to be very difficult

Comment: @Sebastián  `'{"id": {"N": "1"}, "data": {"S": "'${fecha_termino}'"}}'` should work.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/19n5om2 I did your advice, but the row added just appears 'date', I tried with an echo with the row added was 'echo date'

Comment: @Sebastián Sorry, but unless you provide exact details of your code, this can go for ever. Please edit your question with exactly what you are doing. Not some partial screenshots that do not relate to your question.

Comment: thanks for yours advices, please see new details

Comment: @Sebastián It should be `fecha_termino_var=$(date +'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: and then like this?: aws dynamodb put-item --table-name mcp_control_proceso --item         '{"id_proceso": {"N": "1"}, "fecha_proceso": {"S": "20210707170487"}, "status": {"S": "OK"}, "fecha_termino": {"S": "'${fecha_termino_var}'"} }' --region us-east-1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234680/discussion-between-sebastian-and-marcin).